# fullPage js - use two moveTo() functions in succession

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I have 4 sections, built using fullPage js and the 3rd section in turn has four slides. I am using a horizontal navigation on the slides even for vertical scrolling, so my navigation turns out as shown in the picture
[image]

If the links on my menu are clicked when in the slides section, I want to move left to the first slide, and then move up or down depending on which section' s link has been clicked.

I know that `moveTo()` can be used to move to any section or slide, so I am using it twice in succession. I can't just get it to work correctly.

the `onLeave` option's code is for the horizontal scrolling and the `afterSlideLoad` 's code is for the left motion to go to the first slide and then up or down.

Anyone has any ideas?

link to website: https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/spotify-circle-animation

HTML (menu):

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menu-link" data-menuanchor="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link" data-menuanchor="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link" data-menuanchor="projects"><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link" data-menuanchor="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var slideIndex = 1, sliding = false, slideLinkClick = false, link;

$('#fullpage').fullpage({

                    anchors: ['home','about','projects','contact'],

                    loopHorizontal: false,

                    fixedElements: '#toggle,#overlay',

                    slidesNavigation: true,

                    menu: '#menu',

                    controlArrows: false,

                    slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',

                    recordHistory: false,

                    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {

                        if (index == 3 && !sliding) {

                            if (direction == 'down' && slideIndex < 4) {

                                sliding = true;
                                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
                                slideIndex++;
                                return false;

                            } else if (direction == 'up' && slideIndex > 1) {

                                sliding = true;
                                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideLeft();
                                slideIndex--;
                                return false;

                            }

                        } else if (sliding) {

                            return false;

                        }

                    },
                    afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
                        sliding = false;

                        $('.menu-link').on('click', function(){
                            link = $(this).attr('data-menuanchor');
                            link= "'"+link+"'";
                            console.log(link);
                            $.fn.fullpage.moveTo('projects',0);
                            slideLinkClick = true;
                        });

                        if(index === 3 && slideIndex === 0 && slideLinkClick === true) {
                            console.log(link);
                            $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(link);
                            slideLinkClick = false;
                            console.log(slideLinkClick);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I think the `if` section should be inside the click handler. The problem is, you are assigning the click handler which is executed when someone clicks on `.menu-link`. But whereas in that case the `if` block is not executed.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. Additionally, the first motion, where it moves to the first slide also stops working

Comment: Hey I just saw that there is a callback function in the fullPage.js API. Like `aftreLoad`, `afterSliderLoad` and etc. Are you sure you are making proper use of them? To do one action after another. Here: http://designify.me/tutorials/fullpage-js-create-beautiful-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/#.WbJDM9MjEfE

Comment: @kaushik94 - I am using the callbacks, I referred to the documentation

Comment: Easier to just use the [Scroll Horizontally extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html) that fullPage.js provides.